# How to put a word into an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to put English words into an element with JQuery. for example :

before:

```
رایجترین نوع این پارامتر کلاس پایه eventArgs می باشد.
```

after :

```
رایجترین نوع این پارامتر کلاس پایه <bdo>eventArgs</bdo> می باشد
```

Comment: Do you know these words ahead of time or are they unknown and could be anything?

Comment: How are they specified?  Looks like a simple js `.replace()` might suffice

Comment: yes , they are 70 keywords of C#.Net

Comment: @younes What have you tried?

Comment: I want simple way to put these words into bdo tag

Comment: @younes Show some of your research. Don't expect SO users to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to match word characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the underscore. Not sure if this will cover every scenario for you though.

```
// Pulls text out of element, I assumed span
var text = $('span').text();
// matches the characters above
var find = text.match(/\w+/);
// Replaces what was found with those characters wrapped in your bio tag
var newText = text.replace(find, "<bdo>" + find + "</bdo>");
// Puts text back in element
$('span').html(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace` and regex to accomplish what you are looking for.

EG:

```js
$('button').click(function (event) {
   $('p').html($('p').text().replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, "<bdo>$1</bdo>"));
});
```

```css
bdo {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>"رایجترین نوع این پارامتر کلاس پایه eventArgs می باشد."</p>

<button>
Replace Text With Element
</button>
```

Comment: When I use this code, images are hidden within the text !!!how to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Are there other elements in your text? I posted my answer under the assumption that you are only dealing with text (not elements). If that's not the case I would suggest updating your question to include all details of your problem.

Comment: I have other element in my text. but i want just English words and symbol into bdo tag

Comment: I want only English words and symbols are within the paragraph placed inside bdo tag.